# Parametric Region only showing half of region

Tags: regions

I have defined the region as such:

```
Region[
 ParametricRegion[
  {r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]},
  {{θ, 0, 2π}, {r, 0, 2+Cos[θ]}}
 ], Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

However it only shows half of the limaçon:

[image]

Whereas the polar plot of the same function over the same interval [0,2π] represents the entire thing:

```
PolarPlot[2 + Cos[θ], {θ, 0, 2π}]
```

[image]

Now, I know I am using a workaround, by defining a polar plot with x and y, and this is likely the cause of the issue.  So, how would I define the region that I want to, or any region really, using polar coordinates?

*Note:* Changing the interval to [-π,π] draws the full limaçon, but I would rather not have to play around with the interval every time I have a new function.  I preferably want a solution that allows me to easily and correctly define a polar region.

Comment: What is this `Region` function? It seems to be undefined in my version (v11.0)!

Comment: Are parametrized domains supported?

Comment: No such problem with v12.2.0 on Win7-x64: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0FV.png)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[(0 <= θ <= 2 π) && (0 <= r <= 2 + Cos[θ]), {r, θ}];
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ]}, {r, θ} ∈ R]
```